# How to hide assets in library using ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

When I create *aar* file and add it to the fresh project and compile it everything works but in the file explorer in my OS, I can find all the assets in the project folder (in IDE they are not visible, I can't find them anyways). How to deal with that? Is there any additional option in ProGuard?

Comment: By definition, developers using your library need whatever resources, assets, and manifest entries that you put into that library. Otherwise, the library cannot work. In addition, everybody on the planet can get at the resources, assets, and manifest entries from your library, by examining any app that uses the library.

If you have something that you do not want people to see, do not distribute it.

Comment: @CommonsWare What about DexGuard?

Comment: First, I do not know if that works on libraries (AFAIK, it does not). Second, it does not prevent anyone from accessing your assets, resources, and  manifest entries. It only means that they now need to know how to program a computer in order to get at your assets and resources.

Comment: This is one of their features, read on their site: "Encryption of classes, Cordova/Phonegap applications, strings, assets, resource files, native libraries and custom WebViews"

Comment: In easy words: it just gives encryption, aye?

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK that only works on apps, not on libraries. And since the encryption key and algorithm are baked into the app, anyone with sufficient programming skills should be able to decrypt the materials.

Comment: @CommonsWare if I tell you that those files in assets are mainly JavaScript files, is there any other way to hide them?

Comment: Get rid of them. Otherwise, no.